# Microsoft Outlook rule to **detect** missing daily email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, macros, rules

I work in production support and daily I get an email stating that all is OK.  If I don't get the email then maybe there is an issue with my SMTP server or my application not sending emails.  Opening and reading an email that says all is OK is repetitive and can be missed.

I would like a rule to run daily at 10 am to check for the **absence** of the all OK email today.  This way outlook will alert me with a popup if our system is not sending emails out.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a such Outlook inbox rule that alerting you the missing messages.As a workaround, you could create an inbox rule that alerting you when the daily email is delivered to your mailbox, and store them in a customized folder. If you don receive an alert, or you review the folder, find if the scheduled mail misses.

Answer (score 0):

It order to popup, you'll need to write a VBA script. But there is a basic workaround, maybe it'll suite your needs: just create a [Custom Search Folder](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-search-folders-to-find-messages-or-other-outlook-items-c1807038-01e4-475e-8869-0ccab0a56dc5). Provide a criteria you need to detect you OK email (Subject/From/...) and set the **Time received = Today**. After that, in the folder properties, set the **Show total number of items** option. Now you can see if you have any OK emails for today right in your mailbox.